# ¿Por qué no me funciona la propiedad DateTime.Date en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, date, datetime

Estoy realizando una consulta sql desde asp.net framework 4.8, la cual tiene un filtro por rango de fechas. Siempre que se ejecuta la consulta salta el error: : 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'. El parámetro de fecha llega con el formato 
`yyyy-MM-dd`, es un string, lo convierto a DateTime asi

```
DateTime fechaDesde = (DateTime.ParseExact(DOB, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

De la variable fechaDesde me interesa solo el dia, mes y año para poder comparar con la base de datos (Oracle SQL Developer version 19.2.0.206), la cual tiene la configuracion `DD/MM/YYYY` lo corroboré viendo aquí `select * from nls_session_parameters;`
Como sólo quiero la parte de la fecha, a la variable  fechaDesde le aplico la propiedad .Date, quedando `fechaDesde.Date` ,esto lo guardo en una variable Datetime, que sirve tanto para DateTime como para Date, pero el resultado siempre es `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`. Segun la documentacion de microsoft, 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8 
se accede a esa propiedad asi `DateTime->Date` pero en realidad no funciona porque sale error, dicen que se aplica a .Net framework 4.8, pero solo con punto deja de tener error, pero de igual manera el resultado no es Date, sino `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`, creo que por esta razon me está saliendo 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'. Todo el proceso que hago con la fecha de inicio, tambien lo hago con la fecha final del rango. Gracias por la ayuda desde ya.

Comment: Quiero añadir  que tambien probé convirtiendo la fecha en string con el mismo formato que maneja la BD `string x = fechaDesde.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` pero el error persiste.

Comment: El error ha sido solucionado de la sgte manera: en el query, tuve que agregarle la funcion `TO_DATE(x, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, de esta manera ya no tuvo conflictos.

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de dato `DateTime` siempre va a retornar una parte del `time` sin importar que uses el `.Date` ya que este normaliza el tiempo haciando que sea igual para todas las fechas, pero el `hh:mm:ss tt` siempre va a estar presente

El problema con `Oracle` es que debes usar parametros cuando ejecutas la consulta

```
DateTime fechaDesde = (DateTime.ParseExact(DOB, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

string query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campoFecha > :fechaDesde";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query , db);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("fechaDesde", fechaDesde));
```

asignando el parametro deberia tomar correctamente el tipo de dato como fecha interpretando cual es el mes

Comment: Gracias @leandro, voy a tomar este consejo para futuras ocasiones.